# Raspberry Pi Python Talkey (TTS) + Cron

Tags: linux, cron, python, raspberry-pi, text-to-speech

I have written this little Python script to listen to the BBC RSS Top Stories feed on my Raspberry Pi

So first of all because I have problems with the 3.5 mm Jack (no sound), I went into

```
sudo raspi-config
```

then in Advanced Options > Audio I chose "Force 3.5 mm ('headphone') jack"

(This always works for me)

So the jack configuration out of the way, let's check out the script:

```
# morning.py

import feedparser # To scrape the BBC Feed
import talkey # The TTS service I'll be using

d = feedparser.parse("http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml")
tts = talkey.Talkey(
    engine_preference=['espeak'],
    espeak={
        'deafults': {
            'words_per_minute': 100,
            'variant': 'f4',
       }
   }
)
for entry in d.entries:
    tts.say(entry.title + ":" + entry.summary)
```

I wanted the script to run at a specific time (morning) so I used Cron. This is what I typed in

```
crontab -e
0 8 * * * sudo python morning.py >/dev/null 2>&1 # inside crontab
```

(The morning.py script is located in the 'pi' directory.)

However the script will not run at the specified time for some reason.

(It runs perfectly without Cron though.)

Comment: Have you try to specify full path to the files: /bin/sudo /bin/python /path/to/morning.py

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of trouble with crontab
Every time I have to edit the "crontab -e" I should declare:
    export EDITOR=vim
That's why I put this in my ~/.bashrc file
    vim ~/.bashrc
this contains the shortcuts you can check with
    alias -p #(here in a-b-c sort)
Now to into your home directory

```
cd ~/ #or
cd
```

let it edit vith the vim-editor

```
vim .bashrc
```

push "G" => you'll come at the end of this file
than write this in as following:"i"(insert mode); than type this in

```
alias e='export EDITOR=vim' # activated at the next Terminal session
```

If you are done hit "ESC" than save with ":wq" Enter

In this case the next terminal session (Ctrl+Shift+N) will know this shortcut. Just "e" and hit Enter and write in the command line

```
whereis python
```

Result something this: /usr/bin/python2.6
go to the paht where your "script.py" is, and let it to be executable

```
chmod +x myscript.py; # do not need a sudo;
```

or

```
chmod 755 myscript.py; # do not need a sudo; you are the user
```

after that edit your "crontab -e" (as I know "crontab -l" is for sudo)

Just hit the "e" (this will activate your EDITOR to vim)

```
crontab -e
0 8 * * * /usr/bin/python2.6 ~/myfolder/morning.py >/dev/null 2>&1 # inside crontab
```

hope this will solve your project

Comment: 0 8 * * * /usr/bin/python2.6 ~/myfolder/morning.py >/dev/null 2>&1 # inside crontab

Comment: Welcome to Unix Stackexchange! The formatting on this mesage makes it somewhat hard to read.  I tried to edit it, but I am afraid that I will get something wrong.  Can you please edit your post and highlight the code by either starting the line with 4 spaces or surrounding a keyword with the backward quote.

Comment: You was right, and to tell the truth I had no experience with formating regularly a post like this. Thank you informing me!

Comment: Well Done, that looks much better.  Once again, welcome.and thank you for your contribution.